# GMSMarker iconView weird behaviour when transform the marker

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, marker

I am currently using Google Maps in an iOS application where I used iconView for the Marker when I tapped on the marker and scale the current selected marker other marker looks weird.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool
{
    if marker.userData != nil
    {
        let index : Int = Int(marker.userData as! String)!

        //small all the marker
        _ = markers.map { (marker) in
            marker.iconView?.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }

        markers[index].iconView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
        setVenuePin(index: index)
    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "weird behaviour"? Please attach a screenshot.

Comment: insted of it you can change the iconview it will be more responsive

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?